# Emulate some of spacemacs leader keys in Vim

Tags: key-bindings

I now use Spacemacs Hybrid mode for local files but I often have to SSH into older machines that either do not have a modern Emacs (24) or only have Vim installed.

Thus I have gotten used to editing with vanilla Vim on these remote machines. That being said I have been aiming for some consistency these days and would like some of the Helm-like SPC leader key things to work on Vim so I was curious if anyone knows of a plugin for Vim out there that somewhat matches spacemacs (ie <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> instead of `:bd`).

I already have vimacs installed for my messed up "hybrid" mind. Just need the leader key mappings.

**TL;DR: make Vim a little more like spacemacs.**

Comment: Like you said, this question is about Vim rather than Emacs, and isn't on-topic for this site.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific about the behaviour you want. If you just want to map `:` to space, then: `nnoremap : <space>` is sufficient.

Comment: He actually wants *all* the vim-like combinations defined by Spacemacs (i.e. starting with the `Space` leader key) to be brought back to Vim ... of course, mapping stuff is so easy in Vim, the sensible suggestion would be for the OP to create his own maps, as need arises (open `vimrc`, add the map, re-source the file, close). Because I wonder what Vim person has that inclination of reading all those Spacemacs config layers, extract the modal parts, and import them back to a Vim plugin ... although, who knows, some people today would do anything for fame :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try [space-vim](https://github.com/liuchengxu/space-vim), which is intended for those who using vim and spacemacs at the same time. Its goal is to switch from spacemacs to vim painlessly.

What's more, [spacevim](https://github.com/ctjhoa/spacevim) is also a good choice. It can be seen as a full vim distribution or a set of key bindings similar to spacemacs. You can pick out one that suits you best.

Comment: +1 I actually prefer the https://github.com/ctjhoa/spacevim (one you mention) over https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim (the one I mentioned). ctijhoa's version is more emacs like but seems to have issues with neovim (albeit I think there is a fork that sort of works).

Comment: @AdamGent You could all have a try then choose the one you like. Personally, I prefer [space-vim](https://github.com/liuchengxu/space-vim), it looks more beautiful at least ~

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the github user sthysel made a port of spacemacs on Vim: https://github.com/sthysel/vim-spacemacs

You can install it with your favorite plugin manager and then you'll have to set your leader key to `<space>` with:

```
let mapleader = "\<SPACE>"
```

**Note** That it might be not as complete as spacemacs, you can see [here](https://github.com/sthysel/vim-spacemacs/blob/master/plugin/spacemacs.vim) the list of mappings created by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I marked @statox answer correct because it works nicely with regular vim. However if you are using NeoVim then there is [**SpaceVim**](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim) which is exceedingly impressive.